# Procedure to upgrade SVN server on ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu, svn

I have an ubuntu server running SVN server 1.6 with apache2, which I want to upgrade to 1.7

Running 'apt-get install subversion' just upgraded me to 1.6.6, not to 1.7
What command should I use exactly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [the following instruction](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1876156) and **tested them to be working**

```
echo "deb http://opensource.wandisco.com/ubuntu lucid svn17" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/svn.list
sudo wget -q http://opensource.wandisco.com/wandisco-debian.gpg -O- | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes,

just upgrading the server binaries is enough.
The DB format has not changed on server side.

Look at the secion Compatibility Concerns

http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.7.html

Comment: Yes, but what command should I use exactly to upgrade the binaries?

Comment: Sorry, overlooked that part of your question.. :(